# Problem with ee()->input->post in plugin

Tags: plugin, 2.7.3

The following plugin code works fine for me locally running mamp and php 5.5.3, but returns nothing on our dev server running php 5.5.8:

```
$rating     = ee()->input->post('rating');
return $rating;
```

Both environments are running EE 2.7.3. The template code is as follows:

```
<form id="ratingform" action="/globals/process-save-and-rate/{last_segment}/10/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="rating" id="rating" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="{XID_HASH}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What is in 'process-save-and-rate' is as follows (and I know this should be a module to process the form):

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_4}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="1"}
        {exp:pp_general:save_property entry_id="{segment_3}" myaction="1"}
    {/case}
    {case value="2"}
        {exp:pp_general:save_property entry_id="{segment_3}" myaction="2"}
    {/case}
    {case value="3"}
        {exp:pp_general:save_property entry_id="{segment_3}" myaction="3"}
    {/case}
    {case value="10"}
        {exp:pp_general:save_and_rate entry_id="{segment_3}"}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

If anyone can shed any light on why this is not working, I'd be very grateful. As I say, I'm just getting a blank screen whereas it should be outputting the value of the $rating variable.

Secure forms is turned on in EE. Turning it off and removing the XID hash gives the same result.

I'm not seeing any php errors so am a bit stumped.

Jim

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump($rating)? If it's not set it should return a boolean false.

Comment: Where $rating isn't set, the output I get is this: string(0) "". It isn't an array though. It should always be a single value.

Comment: sorry, meant var_dump(ee()->input->post()).

Comment: This is weird - I've getting "bool(false) " no matter what I enter in the form. That means that the post variables aren't being picked up by EE. Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Just to rule out switchee misbehaving - could you try with 4 simple {if}{/if} statements instead of the switchee code? What happens then?

Comment: Great suggestion Erwin. I actually removed all the conditionals and just had the plugin tag. Made no difference at all, so look like switchee is fine.

Comment: This seems so weird that I'm now wondering whether it could be something to do with the Nginx configuration. Will take a look.

Comment: any follow-up on this? Just curious.

Comment: So far I've not been able to see anything wrong with the Nginx config. However, I appear to have found a fix for the problem - converting the plugin to a module instead. Once this is 100% confirmed I'll post this as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is now fixed. What I did was convert the plugin to a module and use EE's ACT action urls to handle the form posting.

I got some great tips from looking at Andrew Weaver's EE Addon Recipes site (http://ee-recipes.com) so thanks to Andrew for putting that out there.

Comment: don't forget authentication before processing POST-ed data.